# Any way to add an icon or text in each day box before the day number (month view)

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

Using fullcalendar-scheduler in month view I would like to put an image and/or text on the top left of each day. In other words, where the day number is in the top right corner of each day, I want to put something in the top left corner of each day.

My calendar shows jobs that are scheduled each day. Some jobs might have only one worker assigned, while other jobs could have five people. Hovering the mouse over a job displays the workers names, which is great. But, I need a better visual indicator on each day so it's easy to see the status of the whole month at a glance.

I haven't decided exactly what this will look like - I'm considering two options:

```
1) display a small green ball if less that 10 people currently
assigned, otherwise a small red ball if 10 or more people

2) display the actual number of people, like (4 of 12)
```

Either way, I don't know how to inject the custom data. Any suggestions?

Comment: I should say that I've gotten pretty close with this, but all it does is replace the day number:  ```dayCellContent: { html: '<span style="text-align: left; ">Hello?</span>' }```

Comment: if you use the callback function variant of dayCellContent, then you'll have a lot more control to be able to inject data into it.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I just wanted to make sure I was looking in the right place before wasting too much time. I've got almost everything perfect now. The last remaining problem is that I can't get my icon centered vertically on the line with the text. The icon appears to be stuck to the top of the div. Trying to use vertical-align: middle is not working.